# Distinguish between Page Submit and Direct Link in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 21. How do I distinguish between page accessed by 'Submit' button and a direct link?

When I actually want to do:
I want the page to clear session state when accessed directly (i.e., using a pre-generated link like f?p=...), but keep session state (of course) when 'Submit' button is clicked.

According to [APEX 19 Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/understanding-substitution-strings.html#GUID-6E97BB81-925A-443F-BE2A-D47722330228) (can't Google APEX 21 doc),

> Each application button sets the value of REQUEST to the name of the button or to the request value attribute associated with the button

However, :REQUEST is null when I use submit button. So this is not working for me.

Also tried 'Redirect Page to this Application', but it can't pick up new values in the form.

Note: I have no control on the direct link. I want to avoid changing it if there are alternative solution.

Comment: v21 docs available here https://apex.oracle.com/doc212

Comment: Submit request value generally used during processing, not subsequent page. You could add your own request values to your direct links to differentiate.

Comment: you state "REQUEST is NULL". How are you checking this ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie, I used `APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGE` to log :REQUEST it in the debug log. When I click the Submit message, this logs null. When I call this page from another page (using 'Redirect to Page to this Application' which REQUEST set, the `APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGE` logged the REQUEST value.

Comment: At what point did you log it ? What does "when I click the Submit message" mean ? I did a test. If a request value is set in the url, it will be visible in the before header/after header/before regions. If a page is submitted, the request value (button name)  is only visible in the after submit and processing point. By default that request is not propagated to the next page.

Comment: But to answer your question, the answer below is totally correct - I suggest accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to specify one or more pages in the [`ClearCache` section](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03019) of the link you are creating.  This comes after the `Debug` section and before the `itemNames` section.  The URL

```
f?p=123:456:&SESSION.:::456:P456_ITEM1:Value
```

creates a link to page 456 in application 123, clears the cache for page 456, and sets the value of `P456_Item1` to "Value".

Comment: Thanks for noting the `ClearCache` section of the link. However, I can't (easily) change the direct link. Updated the original question.